# Pre Increment vs Post Increment Java Flaws

Tags: java

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        int key = array[i];
        
        while (i > 0 && key < array[i-1]) {
            array[i--] = array[i-1];
        }
    
        array[i] = key;
    }
```

I got this piece of code and don't really understand how the `array[i--]` part works. Based on my understanding, `i--` changes the value of `i` after the statement is ran while `--i` changed the value of `i` after expression. However, in this case, `array[i--]` is not the same as `array[i]` and put the `i--` part under the statement. Can everyone explain? Doesn't this means that `array[i--]` in this case is the same as `array[--i]`?

Comment: "Based on my understanding, i-- changes the value of i after the statement is ran" - no, it changes the value of `i` after *that expression* has been evaluated. *Not* after the whole statement has executed.

Comment: And then: "while --i changed the value of i after expression" - no, that changes the value of `i` *before* evaluating the expression. So if `i` is 5 to start with, both `i--` and `--i` will end up with `i` being set to 4 after the expression is evaluated, but `i--` will evaluate to 5, and `--i` will evaluate to 4.

Comment: I would strongly advise that you investigate this behavior with simpler code, without any array access etc.

Comment: maybe a better description¹ of the post-fix decrement `--` is that the variable is decremented, but the result of that operation is the value before it is decremented. And, since both sides (operands) of the assignment (any operator) are evaluated left-to-right, `array[i--]` is fully evaluated before the right side is evaluated- so when the right side (`array[i-1]`) is evaluated, `i` is already decremented. If you move the `i--` after the assignment, that is not the case. || **¹** [JLS 15.14.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.3)

Answer (score 0):

Learn about `pre` and `post` increment operator.
**Try to avoid such type of statement, because it decreases code readability**

```
    int a=5,b;

    b = ++a; //equivalent to: a = a+1; b = a;
    System.out.println(b+" - "+a); // 6 - 6

    a = 6;
    b = a++; //equivalent to: b = a; a = a+1
    System.out.println(a+" - "+b); // 7 6


    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4};

    int i=3;

    while(i!=0){
        System.out.println(arr[i--]); // 4 3 2
// --- equivalent to below two statments: ---
//            System.out.println(arr[i]);
//            i = i-1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array[i--] = array[i-1];
```

is same as

```
array[i] = array[i - 1 - 1];
i = i - 1; // or: i -= 1; or: i--; or: --i;
```

The post decrement `i--` will happen directly after reading the value of `i` and not after finishing the complete statement.

Comment: or similar to `var tmpi - i; i = i - 1; array[tmpi] = array[i-1];`

Comment: @user16320675 What do you mean by `var tmpi - i;`?

Comment: sorry, it should've been:  similar to  `var tmpi = i; i = i - 1; array[tmpi] = array[i-1];`